# how can i set custom height and width constants for an UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, alert, uialertcontroller

so i have created a UIAlertController in my Xcode Project. Now i want to know if its possible to set the width and the height of the AlertWindow, because the default UIAlertController is to small. Even when i set the frame of the UIAlertController, the alert that pops up has still the default height and width.

heres my code:

```swift
  func passwordAlert() {
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "type in some text", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        alert.view.layer.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 500)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "add", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

Comment: No. You don't customize `UIAlertController`. You create your own component if needed (plenty of them in GitHub/CocoaControls/Carthage/Cocoapods, etc.)

Comment: and then i have to import my own customized alertcontroller ?

Comment: It wont be an UIAlertController... it will be your own UIview component that you can set the way you want